# How to set a permanent background color with a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my goal is quite simple. I have a script which changes the backgroud color by a click and returns the color to the basic one with the second click.

**CSS**

```
body { 
    background-color: white;
}

.negative {
    background-color: black;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(zasuvka).click(function(){
    $("body").toggleClass(negative);
});
```

When I am going throught the webpage, I mean when I am clicking on the menu links of my webpage (contact, gallery..), the background color is returning to the basic one. I want to make the script permanent till the button which runs this script is pressed again. I hope you get it. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: If you want to do it only from javascript you'll need to use cookies to be able to preserve the state between requests.

Comment: Use cookies or Storage (HTML5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

    var bg = localStorage.getItem('bg');
    if (bg && bg == 'neg') $('body').addClass('negative');

    $('#zasuvka').click(function(){
        $("body").toggleClass('negative');
        localStorage.setItem('bg', (bg&&bg=='neg') ? 'norm' : 'neg');
    });

</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/VSmP9/)

Comment: This works almost great, however not perfectly. The problem is that when I close and reopen the webpage the background color doesnt returns to the basic one. Im sorry for confusion but this solution is more permanent than i wanted. Any ideas? Althought thank you very much.

Comment: @user3473897 - so what you really want is to just keep this going for the session. To do that you can swap to sessionStorage instead of localStorage, the rest of the code is exactly the same, here's a -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/VSmP9/1/**

Comment: And note that in most browser the session will end when the browser is closed, not just the tab.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `localStorage` to save the toggle status of the class, then set it anew on page load. Keep in mind, however, that this will risk a FOUC (Flash of unstyled content) in that the background will be white until the script loads, after which it may suddenly change to black. You could alternatively save the value in a cookie and use server-side code to set the initial background colour.

Comment: I don't think he needs server-side to check a cookie.

Comment: The server-side cookie code is to prevent the FOUC.

Comment: Or he can trigger the js toggle right on the head, without any dependencies (like jQuery), right?

Comment: Right after `<body>` then? I'm just trying to figure this without actually needing a 'server-side'

Comment: It could work, but you still have the chance of FOUC depending on certain factors - especially if you then move the script to an external file (as you should avoid inline scripts as a general rule)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery cookie https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie to save the state between requests than check the status on refresh.